# Python: Unit test of a function not returning anything, but changing state of the object

Tags: python, testing

I have a function that doesn't return any value, but changes the internal state of its object. E.g.:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._status = None

    def doSomethingThatResultsInChangingStatus(self):
        ...do some computing...
        self._status = newStatus
```

The `_status` instance variable is meant to be private, so even though Python technically lets me check its status after the function call, I feel that I shouldn't be doing that. The way I am checking it now is by having a getter function for the `_status` variable, but that's fundamentally similar to checking the private variable directly. What is the proper way to test this kind of function?

Comment: Don't be shy about accessing `_status`.  Providing a getter is just silly.  Though you might think about how to test this using just the externally visible API.  There's a reason you're changing the state of the object.  Something different must happen later because of it.  Test that.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I feel like I am cheating because Python lets me access private variables. So you're saying that if I was writing this in a language that doesn't let me access private data, I should just create a getter for the private member just for the sake of testing? For some reason, this smells to me, but maybe I am unnecessarily too purist.

Comment: Also, I can check it by verifying the output of some other method whose return value depends on the _status variable value (which is what you basically suggested). But then I am involving two distinct methods in the single test and if there is a bug in the latter method, the test might pass even if it should fail.

Comment: I'm not offering any advice about what to do in other languages.  In Python, it's silly to write a getter for that attribute.  If you want to see if the status changed, just examine the attribute you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go ahead and evaluate the `_status` directly:

```
def test():
    a = A()
    a.doSomethingThatResultsInChangingStatus()
    assert a._status == 'changed correctly'
```

That's one of the very reasons we use Python right? To not to have to devise silly contraptions like *test-only-wrappers-around-private*. Remember, [we are all consenting adults here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#we-are-all-consenting-adults). Private in Python is just to demark members that are not intended for general client usage and may not be safe to use if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I ended up doing it the way you described. My concern was a proper way to handle these situations in general, in more strict languages such as Java. I guess, like you said, this is one of the reasons we chose Python - it's awesome :).

Comment: Actually, naming it `_status` makes it an implementation detail, not part of the interface. While you *can* do this, it ties your test too tightly to the current implementation. Using the public interface would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Does 'doSomethingThatResultsInChangingStatus' return any value? If it returns nothing, you can use its return value to indicate whether status changed.

Or, you can have a `self.status_changed` member for this purpose. Once changed, set the value to True, and reset to False where applicable

Comment: the doSomethingThatResultsInChangingStatus doesn't return anything, so this isn't applicable. If it did return something, this question wouldn't be asked ;).

Comment: And adding extra member self.status_changed for this purpose is probably the least graceful way to implement the test.

Comment: I mean why not add a return value in 'doSomethingThatResultsInChangingStatus'? If the only thing the function does is to change state, it's probably meaningful to add a bool return value to indicate whether it changes something

Comment: Whether '_status' should be read directly depends on the design on your class. If the status is supposed to be access by outside, just rename it to 'status', that's more graceful. If you dont want outside to access the exact value of 'status', instead only allow outside to know whether the value changed, then I don't see why 'status_changed' is not graceful. In my opinion, the only case '_status' could be better is that only unit testing access the member from outside, not any other codes

Comment: One more case to use '_status', if you are unit testing other people's codes, cannot modify the codes, then '_status' is probably the only way

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to access the private variable through some getter function.

```
class A:
    def getStatus(self):
         return self._status
```

Then use this in the assert statement:

```
def test():
   a.changeStatus()
   assert a.getStatus() == 'newStatus'
```

[Updated]

Or as suggested by @chepner, use properties:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self)
        self._status

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self._status

    @status.setter
    def status(self, value):
        self._status = value
```

And you can access status through `a.status`.

More info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: A property would be better.

Comment: @chepner do you mean using @property?